# Dynamically Adjusting the Height of an iFrame Based on Submit Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a form I'm pulling in that generates an iFrame for the Payment portion of things.  The height is fine, but when you click "submit" and the form has errors the error message(s) push the submit below the iframe's height, causing it to disappear. I've been playing around with some JavaScript to dynamically adjust the height by binding the event, but no luck thus far, thanks.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("embedded123frm757809").contentWindow;
    iframe.$(".submit").bind("click",
    function(){
     $("#embedded123frm757809").css({height: iframe.$("body").outerHeight()
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using

```
$("#embedded123frm757809").css({height: iframe.$("body").outerHeight()
```

Use:

```
$("#embedded123frm757809").attr('height',iframe.$("body").outerHeight());
```

Recommend to use:

```
iFrame = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
```

Assuming that your `iFrame` is the first `iFrame` of the page, or the only one.

Because your ID is weird and seems to be generated.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, after implementing this posed another problem, the iFrame ID doesn't load with the initial page, so now I'm getting a error of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method '$' of null" I think I'm going to just add a min-height via CSS, thanks.

Comment: Wait, you can access the iFrame without needing the ID :) see edit